# How complex can a Hibernate transaction be

Tags: java, hibernate

This is probably more a "design" or style question:  I have just been considering how complex a Hibernate transaction should or could be.  I am working with an application that persists messages to a database using Hibernate.

Building the message POJO involves factoring out one-to-many relationships from the message into their respective persistent objects.  For example the message contains a "city" field.  The city is extracted from the message, the database searched for an equivalent city object and the resulting object added to the message POJO.  All of this is done within a single transaction:

- Start transaction
- test for duplicate
- retrieve city object
- setCity(cityObject) in message object
- retreive country object
- setCountry(countryObject) in message object
- persist message object
- commit End transaction

In fact the actual transactions are considerably more complex.  Is this a reasonable structure or should each task be completed within a single transaction (rather than all tasks in one transaction)?  I guess the second question relates to best practice in designing the tasks within a transaction.  I understand that some tasks need to be grouped for referential integrity, however this is not always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you put within your outer transaction boundary, the question is whether you can successfully roll back each action.

Bundle related actions within a boundary, and keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: I assume that there is a performance cost in setting up and closing transactions?  Should I be be mindful of this or would the impact be swamped by the duration of the actual database operations?

Comment: JDBC will just defer to the underlying DB's transaction mechanism. You can then study the space/time complexity of the underlying store's transaction handling to get a better idea. I presume you use MySQL, and if so, I recommend [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html). Obviously, Hibernate, JDBC etc etc will need to create classes, handle exceptions, your VM would need to collect garbage, etc whenever the transaction is rolled back, and this something you can measure too.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions should be grouped according to the business requirements, not technical complexity.   If you have N operations that must succeed or fail together as a unit, then that's what the code should support.  It should be more of a business consideration than a technical one.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple transactions only make sense if the DB isn't left in a stupid state between them, because any single transaction could fail. *Nested* transactions may make sense if any block of activity must be atomic and the entire transaction depends on any of the other atomic units.

Comment: So is it reasonable to say for the example that I gave that retrieving the city and country objects should probably be within separate transactions and then a third transaction should persist the message object?

Comment: I don't see why they'd need to be in separate transactions; the DB won't be left in an indeterminate state from read operations.

Comment: Thanks Dave - I am beginning to make sense of this.  I think I had actually misinterpreted you earlier comment.